# Oracle Member Functions Query

Tags: sql, oracle, member-functions

Within SQL Developer I'm using oracle to create a database, within my database I have salesperson and appointment tables (a few other but are not important)

I want to be able to retrieve how many appointments a particular sales person has via a member function.

Here is what I have so far;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE appointment_t AS OBJECT
(
appointment#        VARCHAR(8),
dateOfApp           date,
timeOfApp           INTEGER(4),
appointmentType     VARCHAR(20),
levelOfInterest     VARCHAR(20),
offerMade           VARCHAR(20),
is_made_for         REF applicant_t,
is_made_by          REF salesperson_t,
is_for              REF property_t
MEMBER FUNCTION     appPerSales RETURN NUMBER
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY appointment_t AS
MEMBER FUNCTION appPerSales RETURN NUMBER IS
    value NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF is_made_by = 'S1000001' THEN
```

However I have no idea how to count through the records in Appointment_t and only add 1 to Value when the is_made_by is the same as one I declared, in this instance its S1000001

Comment: Do you have a table of appointment_t? And wouldn't something that counts appointments for a salesperson be a method of salesperson_t? Does that type have a ref to a table of appointments (or a table of refs)?

Comment: Yes, I only added minimal code so that the code isn't overwhelming. Good suggestion as to having the member function for salesperson, however I still wouldn't know the exact code to do so, I have a table of ref for appointment_t called appointment_list_t which sales person does have a reference to

Comment: So if the salesperson object includes `appointment_list    appointment_list_t`, the `salesperson_t` method function could just return `appointment_list.COUNT`? Or am I oversimplifying?

Comment: Hi, @AlexPoole I've tried what you have suggested, however I keep getting an error stating that appointment_list must be declared, same when I tried it with appointment_list_t the code is as follows `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY salesperson_t as 
 MEMBER FUNCTION appointments RETURN NUMBER IS
  total number;
 BEGIN
  total:= self.appointment_list_t.count;
  return total;
 END;
END;`

Comment: `self.appointment_list.count` not `self.appointment_list_t.count`, you're referring to the type not the instance of that type. I'm still speculating about the attribute name though and i'm not sure if this does what you want...